# How can I get the value of an attribute inside a <span> element?

Tags: javascript, html, attributes

I'm trying to extract a game score from the console for a JS game.

```
document.getElementById("game").getElementsByClassName("game-score")
```

This returns the span which contains the score, which is:

```
<span class="game-score" score="550"></span>
```

I'm trying to extract the score element, so I want just the 550 returned. Is there an easy way to do this?

Comment: Try `.getAttribute('score')`

Comment: Phrasing the question using correct terminology, you would have found the answer sooner: you're not looking for an _element_ (which would be the `<span/>`); rather, you're looking for _an attribute on the `<span>` element._

Answer (score 2):

Use [getAttribute()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getAttribute)

```
document.getElementById("game").getElementsByClassName("game-score")[0].getAttribute("score")
```

```js
console.log(document.getElementById("game").getElementsByClassName("game-score")[0].getAttribute("score"))
```

```html
<div id="game">
  <span class="game-score" score="550"></span>
</div>
```

Comment: It says it's not a function

Comment: You need to reference the span with `[0]`when using `getElementsByClassName`since it returns an array-like object. `document.getElementById("game").getElementsByClassName("game-score")[0].getAttribute("score")`

Comment: Where do I put the [0] tag?

Comment: THANK YOU IT WORKS!

Comment: Okay and final thing. Could you point me in the right direction for creating a script to reload the page until that attribute is greater than a certain value? It's a random number generator I'm playing with and I'm trying to have it reload until that number is > 500.

Comment: Don't know of any such script so you might want to post another question about that

Answer (score 2):

Yes, add `[0].getAttribute("score");` to the end of your existing chain.